# Why does a new Samba share show up later, but not directly after creation?

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba, smb, nemo

My machine: Ubuntu 20.04

I created a share on my samba server. Pretty cut and dry. I can access the server from the backend via ssh, and navigate freely.

However, if I try to reach it from my file explorer (I have both Nautilus and Nemo), it tells me "No such file or directory."

Here's the relevant share config in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[CALL_ARCHIVES]
comment = For samba share of volume tank
vfs objects = glusterfs
glusterfs:volume = tank
glusterfs:logfile = /var/log/samba/glusterfs-tank.%M.log
glusterfs:loglevel = 7
path = /CALL_ARCHIVES
read only = no
valid users = backup root
write list = backup
create mode = 0775
directory mode = 0775
kernel share modes = no
```

**BUT**, if I wait until the next day, I can see it. I tried restarting network services on my end with `service network-manager restart`, but that did not work. What can I flush/clear that will allow me to see it immediately?

One more thing. My samba server has a public address, `192.168.75.36` that is used as a high availability IP, instead of accessing the actual IP of the machine, which is `192.168.75.35`.

Here is the `/etc/ctdb/public_addresses` file:

```
[root@san01 tank]# cat /etc/ctdb/public_addresses 
192.168.75.36/19 enp3s0f1
```

Here are the two physical IPs of the two samba machines:

```
[root@san01 ctdb]# cat nodes 
192.168.75.35
192.168.75.37
```

When I couldn't see the new share from the `75.36` IP, I was able to see it from the `75.35` IP. Now, I can see it from both (`smb://192.168.75.36/ARCHIVE_CALLS` and `smb://192.168.75.35/ARCHIVE_CALLS` within my file explorer).

So what do I need to do to make this visible immediately?

Comment: I had to reboot the server for it to show up right away. The restart of the service did not work for me.

Comment: I only restarted the samba service (which did not work for me either). Rebooting would not be an option for me since many people are connected to the server, and there are other servers that use various shares as mounts.

Comment: Well wait like you said seems the only option.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you are going to have to go to an entire different OS, try Debian.
This will never ever work in Ubuntu.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1807177

Comment: You expect bugs not to get fixed? plus if that is the case the answer is to install glusterfs (it is in universe and samba is in main so the dependency is NOT possible but you can still install glusterfs)

Comment: Yes, its been many years of 0 interest, so it is not going to get fixed. A really really long time, since 2014-01-29

Comment: again: that bug is a dependency issue. Easily manually solved. Please explain what it has to do with the question above? I do not see it

Comment: because the dependency is missing, the share can not exist in this form. If you want to use the vfs with glusterfs, it will just error out as per samba log Error loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/vfs/glusterfs.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/vfs/glusterfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. Followed by error ../../source3/smbd/vfs.c:380(smbd_vfs_init) followed by smdb_vfs_init: vfs_init_custom failed for glusterfs as well as error make_Connection_snum: vfs_init failed for service storage and plenty more

Comment: SO yes, you can install glusterfs, but the share will not work using vfs method as the OP is trying to do

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on your answer to explain why it won't work without us having to read the bug page. Your last two comments are particularly enlightening. Would you mind doing an [edit] of your answer to include the explanation there?